# SQL - Row For Each Criteria - Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, vba

I am trying to create a query that will take a list of data, and give me N rows each time it meets a criteria.

Say I have the following data:

```
 ID  |  Type
  1  |  Vegetables
  2  |  Vegetables
  3  |  Vegetables
  4  |  Fruits
  5  |  Fruits
  6  |  Meats
  7  |  Dairy
  8  |  Dairy
  9  |  Dairy
  10 |  Dairy
```

And what I want is:

```
Type           
Dairy       
Dairy
Dairy
Fruits
Fruits
Meats
Meats
Vegetables
Vegetables
```

The criteria I have is that for every 2 of each Type I count it as a "whole" value. If there is anything more than a whole value, round up to the nearest whole number. So, the Vegetables Type rounds up from 1.5 to 2 rows and the Dairy Type stays at 2 rows.

Then I want to add a row to every Type that is not the last type in the set (Which is why Vegetables only has two rows), perhaps with another column denomination showing that it was the added row.

Comment: Shouldn't Dairy be listed only twice?

Comment: It says it will also add another one to all the sets (but the last one), that's why Dairy has 3

Comment: However, what's the order it should have? alphabetical order?

Comment: I wouldn't do that using SQL but with code instead. It looks like it's more an appearance issue. in MSSQL, you could create a CURSOR, and foreach row, calculate the number of times and insert in a temporary table the value (as many times as the calculated times).

Comment: As Yumei said, @dasblinkenlight Dairy is there three times because of the need to add another.  The order can change, but for now I am sticking with alphabetical. Also, I unfortunately cannot do this in anything but Access-SQL due to the way reports work in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return every type along with the number of times that it has to be repeated:

```
SELECT Type, tot+IIf(Type=(SELECT MAX(Type) FROM tablename),0,1) AS Rep
FROM (SELECT tablename.Type, -Int(-Count([tablename].[ID])/2) AS tot
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY tablename.Type
)  AS s;
```

then my idea is to use a table named [times] that contains every number repeated n times:

```
n
---
1
2
2
3
3
3
...
```

and then your query could be like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (
  SELECT Type, tot+IIf(Type=(SELECT MAX(Type) FROM tablename),0,1) AS rep
  FROM (SELECT tablename.Type, -Int(-Count([tablename].[ID])/2) AS tot
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY tablename.Type
  )  AS s1) s INNER JOIN times ON s.rep=times.n
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the `times` table, could you expand upon it?

Comment: @Elias number 1 is repeated one time, number 2 two times, number 3 three times, number 4 four times, and so on... this way, when we join back the first query with the numbers table every row will be repeated n times... of course you need to know in advance how many times a row could be repeated, this should not be a problem if every row could be repeated only a few times

Comment: @Elias were you able to make it work? is there anything you didn't understand?

Comment: I actually did use something very similar to your solution, but had to start a different question because the differences were too major. Although I didn't quite solve the problem with this, this concept worked. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21787559/1504882

Answer (score 0):

So you want to count the records, divide by 2, round up and then add 1.

```
--Create a temporary table with all numbers from 1 to 1024.
declare @Numbers table
( 
MaxQty INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
) 

WHILE COALESCE(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 0) <= 1024 
BEGIN 
INSERT @Numbers DEFAULT VALUES 
END

--First get the count of records
SELECT [Type], Sum(1) as CNT
INTO #TMP1
FROM MyTable
Group By [Type]

--Now get the number of times the record should be repeated, based on this formula :
--   count the records, divide by 2, round up and then add 1
SELECT [Type], CNT, CEILING((CNT/2)+1) as TimesToRepeat
INTO #TMP2
FROM #TMP1

--Join the #TMP2 table with the @Numbers table so you can repeat your records the
--   required number of times
SELECT A.*
from #TMP2 as A
join @Numbers as B 
on B.MaxQty <= A.TimesToRepeat
```

Not pretty, but it should work.  This still doesn't account for the last type in the set, I'm a little stumped by that part.

Comment: Unfortunately I need this to be usable within Access as it manipulates a local table. I tagged Access, but I wasn't as explicit as about it as I needed.

Comment: Well, all that can be done in Access, although the Numbers table might take a little messing with.  The rest are easy enough, though.