# Access SQL - Create Row For Every 10 Rows And Remainder Found In Group

Tags: sql, ms-access

I can't conceptualize how to do this exclusively with SQL.

Say I have a query that would probably be the subquery in the solution to this problem that produced:

```
Color     |  Count
Brown     |  25
Yellow    |  5
Blue      |  35
```

Using the above result set, I would like a query with the following:

```
Color
Brown
Brown
Brown
Yellow
Blue
Blue
Blue
Blue
```

An alternative solution would be to take the count and do something like:

```
SELECT -Int((-Count(*)/10)) AS Expr1, Color
FROM ColorTable
group by test.Source_City
```

Which, using the above data would produce:

```
Color     |  Count
Brown     |  3
Yellow    |  1
Blue      |  4
```

A solution for this would be to take the Count and write a row for each 1.

Comment: This is a real pain in Access.  Are there any other databases you can use?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is a local table.

Comment: There is no upper limit. In my set of data there is a "color" with a count of over 1000. This query is going to be used to set the page number in a report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have our test data in a table named [InitialCounts]

```
Color   Count
------  -----
Blue       35
Brown      25
Yellow      5
```

and a "numbers table" named [Numbers] containing

```
   n
----
   1
   2
   3
...
9999
```

(or as high as it needs to go, based on the largest number of rows we expect to derive for each color, below).

The query

```sql
SELECT 
    Color, 
    Int(CDbl(Count)/10 + 0.5) AS NewCount
FROM InitialCounts
```

returns

```
Color   NewCount
------  --------
Blue           4
Brown          3
Yellow         1
```

and if we want to produce the repeating rows for each color we can just do

```sql
SELECT NewCounts.Color
FROM
    Numbers,
    (
        SELECT 
            Color, 
            Int(CDbl(Count)/10 + 0.5) AS NewCount
        FROM InitialCounts
    ) AS NewCounts
WHERE Numbers.n <= NewCounts.NewCount
ORDER BY NewCounts.Color
```

returning

```
Color 
------
Blue  
Blue  
Blue  
Blue  
Brown 
Brown 
Brown 
Yellow
```

Comment: I like what you have, but What is `Count` in the NewCount Field

Comment: @Elias Those numbers are the same as the ones in the last sample table of your question, aren't they?

Comment: I just was unsure to what the Count was, but I understand now. Thanks for the help, I was beating my head on that issue for way too long.